# Find a more efficient way to code an If statement in python

Tags: python, if-statement

it's the second time I'm confronted to this kind of code :

```
    if "associé" in gender or "gérant" in gender or "président" in gender or "directeur" in gender:
    gen = "male"
elif "associée" in gender or "gérante" in gender or "présidente" in gender or "directrice" in gender:
    gen = "female"
else:
    gen = "error"
```

I'd like to find a more efficient way to write this code because it looks really bad.

Comment: What is the reason behind using `in`? What are possible values for `gender`?

Comment: `associé` for ex is not a gender. What is a gender in your code?

Comment: Because gender can be a mixt of those (ex : gender = associé gérant or gender = associé président), but the reason of the code is to be able to know if there is a "e" at the end of the word -> in french, "associé" it's a male and "associée" it's a female

Comment: Why not just check: if gender.endswith('e') ? Or do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using lists and `any`:

```
males = ["associé", "gérant", "président", "directeur"]
females = ["associée", "gérante", "présidente", "directrice"]

if any(m in gender for m in males):
    gen = "male"
elif any(m in gender for m in females):
    gen = "female"
else:
    gen = "Error"
```

Comment: That's how I would have done this, but I did not know that you can use "any" ! So thank you Daniel

Comment: maybe the female check should come first, as the only difference in most of them is only a extra letter the shorted one will prove positive in the larger one `"associé" in "associée" == True` and I guess that is undesired

Comment: @Copperfield: you're right, but this would chance the OPs result.

Answer (score 4):

I personally like doing this with [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects). For example:

```
opts = ["associé", "gérant", "président", "directeur"]


if set(opts) & set(gender):
...
```

`&` is used for the set intersection operation which returns a new `set`  with the items shared by the sets on either side of the `&`. This will execute the `if` block only if there is overlap in `gender` and `opts`. You can repeat the process for your `elif` as well, creating a list of the possible options and checking for overlap between that list and `gender`. All together, you could do something like this:

```
male_opts = ["associé", "gérant", "président", "directeur"]
female_opts = ["associée", "gérante", "présidente", "directrice"]

if set(male_opts) & set(gender):
    gen = "male"
elif set(female_opts) & set(gender):
    gen = "female"
else:
    gen = "error"
```

Also, as **@Copperfield** points out. You could increase efficiency even more by making the `*_opt` variables (and potentially even `gender` sets to begin with:

```
male_opts = {"associé", "gérant", "président", "directeur"}
female_opts = {"associée", "gérante", "présidente", "directrice"}
gender = set(gender)

if male_opts & gender:
...
```

## Edit:

The code above assumes that `gender` is an iterable, but it seems from the comments that it is a string instead (e.g., `'associé gérant'`. Although the accepted answer is better at this point, you could still use this solution by making `gender` a set of the words that make up the string:

```
gender = set(gender.split())
```

Comment: instead of calling set on `*_opts` each time, make them set from the start

Comment: looks like `gender` is a string, so this would not work as calling `set` on it will give you a set of the letters

Comment: @Copperfield thanks again. I didn't realize it was a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot have multiple of these stings in one `gender` string, maybe something like this?

```
gen = "error"
for g in ["associé", "gérant", "président", "directeur"]:
    if g in gender:
        gen = "male"
        break
for g in ["associée" "gérante", "présidente", "directrice"]:
    if g in gender:
        gen = "female"
        break
```